# CSS background-position and background-repeat within a CSS sprite

Tags: html, css

I have a box that has a border around it, I split it into 3 parts like in this image (top, middle and bottom):

[image]

The box is placed in a wrapper, here is my piece of code:

CSS:

```
.wrapper { background: url("../images/sprites.png") no-repeat; }
.box-top { background-position: -258px -234px; width: 685px; height: 35px; }
.box-middle { background-position: -258px -271px; width: 684px; height: 1px; }
.box-bottom { background-position: -258px -274px; width: 685px; height: 35px; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="box-top"></div>
   <div class="box-middle">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
   </div>
   <div class="box-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Well the problem is that I am trying to make it to show up normally when text stretches to bottom, but I can't, because all my images are arranged in a sprite, and as you see from `.box-middle` the **height** is **1px** and if I'll change that to more then the whole sprite will show up instead of only image position that I have indicated. Maybe I'm doing something wrong? I want to please you guys to point me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: please explain it more clearly! I can't understand what you are talking about! are you looking for background-size ?

Comment: What specifically you cannot understand? I want that my middle background will stretch toghether with text from ` <div class="box-middle">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use sprites, you need a fixed size. You can't crop a background. You can, however, use `background-size: cover` to stretch it across the width and keep it in proportions. But that wouldn't help you if your background size is small, because stretching up will lose its quality. If your sprite is large, this might be a decent solution, but you'll need to experiment to see how your specific sprite size works with it.

Comment: Ok, so the solution is to extract the middle background from sprites.png and use it apart from it?

Comment: If your height is undeclared and can vary, yes, that is what I would recommend. Sprites are great for buttons, tabs, etc. where the height is fixed and will not change

Answer (score 2):

Well the first thing I noticed is that the top, middle and bottom don't have a background-image set. Is it supposed to be like that?

```
background-image:url('top.png');
background-repeat: repeat-y;
```

Should do the trick.